# How to estimate a ship speed based on weather conditions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have data from some ships, basically the base speed for a list of RPM. But it is know that this speed is not constant and it will change mainly based on whether and load of the ship. Is it any rule of thumb to stime the effect of this varialbes into a ship speed without going to heavy on the math.

Comment: You cannot make any useful conclusions about the speed of any vehicle base on the RPM of its motor, or the RPM of the driving mechanism - propeller, wheels, etc. The power of the engine is the main factor. It is analogous to a car when it's motor is running at a certain RPM. The speed of the car will be different based on the gear that is engaged at the time.

Comment: The rule of thumb is ... All else being the same for a moving ship (or car or airplane or train or other engine-powered device), the higher the RPM of its motor, the faster the object is moving. The "all else being the same" is the controlling statement. Since you say the speed changes with "weather and other factors", you are essentially killing this rule of thumb already. So, for your case, the short answer is ... No, no rule of thumb exists.

Comment: @Fred. Sorry. No. This is done all the time. In each 24 hr period the Chief Engineer will calculate the theoretical distance travelled based on prop RPM and prop pitch. This is then compared to to actual distance travelled as determined by the Navigators. 1-Actual/Theoretical = Slip. It is one of the engineering teams roles to minimise slip, and thus maximise propulsion efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed of a ship and power demand and fuel consumption have to do with many factors.

They are roughly enumerated as follows.

Ship's engine power and draft versus speed curve.

Seas' conditions: draft, roughness, undercurrents.

Wind and meteoritical conditions.

These information are sett into many navigation equipment on board of even small yachts.

They are taught as part of marine engineering courses.

Here is one article covering some of the general concepts and charts, [On the estimation of ship’s fuel consumption and speed curve: A statistical approach](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S2468013315300127/1-s2.0-S2468013315300127-main.pdf?_tid=a6cb3bd2-99a9-48b1-a97b-b00096995428&acdnat=1550170555_633ee92829157e4dd3a6b28a73d9d197)

Comment: Is it reasonable to consider that the speed of the ship will change on a wide range for a given RPM but the fuel consumption for constant RPM will be almost contant as well since the propellers are in contact with water with have same density and resistance all the time?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez, most of engines automatically throttle the power and torque even on cruise at constant RPM, be it by the injectors output or electronics or steam. They have to meet pollution standards.

Comment: Got it! one more thing, if that is the case then the optimal operating point regarding generated power and energy consumed is not at a fixed RPM but rather at a fixed load given by a combination or RPM and Torque, right?

Comment: Yes, and also some other factors like the aspiration content of the engine if it is diesel, etc. There is a lot of subtle fine tuning involved.